MobaXTerm and WSL Debian UI setup not working
I'm connecting to Debian Linux via WSL on Windows 10--everything works fine on the WSL end (and probably Debian's too), but when I try to get the UI up and running, it throws one of these two error messages
$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.
for localhost:0.0. :0.0, or any other garbage I try (going back to the random number approach)
or
connect localhost port 6000: Connection refused
$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.
for localhost:10.0 or :10.0 for $DISPLAY
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks! 
